# Is 枝 used as qí?

Tags: word-choice, word, dictionary

I found that the word 枝 is used not only as zhi but also as qí, but I could not find the entry on macOS Chinese dictionary. Also, when I tried typing it *qi* on iOS, the keyboard didn't show 枝 on the conversion candidate.

That said, Pleco shows the entry 枝 both on zhi and qí. That made me confused, but why is the qí not showed and also is there any difference between two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [zdic](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%9E%9D)

> ● 枝
>
> qí  ㄑㄧˊ
>
> ◎ 古同“歧”，岔。

It lists "qi" as an old usage, as a variant form of "歧".

It is not used in modern mandarin.